# PHP passing session id between different devices

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sessionstorage

My problem is simple.

I have two users on two different devices accessing the same servers pages (page 1 and page 2 respectively ).

I want to use php forms in one page to change the second users page.

(i.e. 1st user on page 1 presses a button and changes the image on 2nd users page 2 , on a separate device).

I thought I could do it by using the 2nd users session ID in the form on the 1st persons page, and fool the server to reload the 2nd users page with the updated info.

But i can see no example of it anywhere on  the web. Is this possible or should I just use Ajax?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not hacking Session ID's like that, they're meant to identify a single user.

If you want data shared between users it's likely you'll be well served using a database, such as MySQL as commonly runs along PHP.

Comment: Thank you Anthony for your answer. The Web App is to be used in a lab type situation so I suppose security is less of a problem, as the only two people using it are the researchers. My client suggested that it was possible using Sessions, but I can only see it being achievable with ajax and a database, hence my query.